# Use Postgres functions on Supabase Client js

Tags: postgresql, supabase, postgrest, supabase-js

I have table 'MyTable' containing the column 'observations' of type jsonb. The Json structure is as following:

```
{
  ...
  obsList: [
    {
      species: 'Goldfinch',
      number: 2
    },
    {
      species: 'House sparrow',
      number: 4
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

If I want to query all the observations of species I can run the query:

```
select obs from  "MyTable" t, jsonb_array_elements(t.observations->'obsList') obs where obs->>'species'='Goldfinch'
```

How do I make the same query using the Supabase js Client library?

I tried:

```
this.supabase.from('MyTable')
  .select('jsonb_array_elements(observations->\'obsList\') as obs')
  .eq('obs:species', 'Goldfinch')
```

and

```
this.supabase.from('MyTable')
  .select('observations->obsList')
  .contains('jsonb_array_elements(o.observations->\'obsList\')', {species: 'Goldfinch'})
```

but I get the error:

`column MyTable.jsonb_array_elements does not exist`

Comment: For complex filtering like this, use Postgres functions. https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/functions

Comment: Yes I figured out that was the best strategy. It's too bad we can't make raw queries.

Comment: @F_sants_ I think raw queries would be too dangerous to execute, even in a limited environment.

Answer (score 1):

As @dshukertjr mentioned, PostgreSQL functions (and views) are the best alternative to tackle complex queries.

To give a concrete example, you could create this view:

```sql
create "MyTableObs" as
  select obs
  from "MyTable" t, jsonb_array_elements(t.observations->'obsList') obs;
```

And do the filtering with Supabase.js:

```js
this.supabase.from('MyTableObs')
  .select()
  .eq('obs->>species', 'Goldfinch')
```

Comment: Thank you Laurence, I ended up using a function, but views also works very well.

Answer (score 0):

You can query for specific array elements in JSONB column using the Superbase JS client:

```
const { data, error } = await superbase
 .from('MyTable)
 .select('observations:obsList(*)')
 .contains('observations.obsList[species]', 'Goldfinch')
```

Comment: Hi NItesh, sorry but doesn't work. The second argument of contains must be an object. Moreover, shouldn't you access the json properties with ->?